# write protection in for loop?

Tags: swift, let

One strange behaviour: I have several objects and arrays:

```
for image in images {
        for nextID in image.parts {
            if nextID.number != 0 {
                if let n = primaryLookUp[nextID.number] {
                    image.parts[0].newID = 0
                    nextID.newID =  0  // cannot assign!!!
                }
            }
        }
```

nextID is simply going through the array of .parts. Does ist become a "let" assignment so I couldn't change anything later on? The

```
image.parts[0].newID = 0
```

is valid!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the explanation for what you are seeing:

The value of a loop variable is immutable, just as if it had been assigned with `let`.

In your first loop, `images` is an array of objects (defined by a `class`).  Since a class object is a reference type, you can alter the fields of the object.  Only the loop variable `image` in that case cannot be assigned.

In your second loop, `image.parts` is an array of `struct`s.  Since a `struct` is a value type, the entire `nextID` and its fields will be immutable within the loop.

If you add `var` to the second loop, you will be able to assign to `nextID.newID`:

```
for image in images {
    for var nextID in image.parts {
        if nextID.number != 0 {
            if let n = primaryLookUp[nextID.number] {
                image.parts[0].newID = 0
                nextID.newID =  0  //  this now works!!!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**but**, you are changing a copy of the `nextID` (since structures copies are by value) and you are not changing the `nextID` contained in the original `image` object.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I want to change the original. So I need to use an index instead to use image.parts[ i ].newID = 0? No simple solution?

Comment: You can change the original with image.parts[i].newID. If the array you are looping on contains objects, then you can change the original. If it is an array of structures, then you'd have to use an index.